# How to add a URL in the message field in Facebook Requests by using facebook api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to include a URL in the message field of Request Dialog. Tried in lots of ways but didn't get a proper solution. Can anyone help me?

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'For more details CLICK HERE',
});
```

Where I want to provide the link as in HTML(<a href="www.abc.com">CLICK HERE</a>)

Comment: You can not! The `message` is just a string!

Comment: seems we can, for ref see this link: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152057277285155&set=a.496176595154.294030.8798180154&type=1&relevant_count=1

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing here is double quotes (") in link breaks the format of string in message so you can use slash ('\') to resolve quotes(") issue like this :

```
string anc  = "<a href=\"www.abc.com\">CLICK HERE</a>";
```